# Can't execute opencv imshow

Tags: opencv, gtk, glib

Executing opencv imshow shows me following error. It worked before. I don't remember I did anything dangerous. I searched on the Internet, but haven't found similar problems. Does anyone has clue about what happened in this situation?

```
[ INFO:0@7.473] global /home/shui/vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/src/4.6.0-754ca27223.clean/modules/highgui/src/registry.impl.hpp (114) UIBackendRegistry UI: Enabled backends(2, sorted by priority): GTK(1000); GTK2(990) + BUILTIN(GTK2)
[ INFO:0@7.473] global /home/shui/vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/src/4.6.0-754ca27223.clean/modules/highgui/src/backend.cpp (90) createUIBackend UI: using backend: GTK (priority=1000)
[ INFO:0@7.473] global /home/shui/vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/src/4.6.0-754ca27223.clean/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp (2364) createWindow OpenCV/UI: Creating GTK window: camera_1_color (1)

(cli_scan:21897): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:32:55.611: cannot register existing type 'AtkObject'

(cli_scan:21897): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:32:55.611: cannot add private field to invalid (non-instantiatable) type '<invalid>'

(cli_scan:21897): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:32:55.611: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

(cli_scan:21897): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:32:55.611: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(cli_scan:21897): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:32:55.611: cannot add private field to invalid (non-instantiatable) type '<invalid>'

(cli_scan:21897): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:32:55.611: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(cli_scan:21897): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:32:55.611: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type '<invalid>'
^C
```